# django url parser using like api/plus/12a23a11133ad

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to parse api/plus/12a23a11133ad
I am unable to write a url parser in django .
I used following , but not working, 
(r'^api/plus/(\?Pd{12})/$', hours_ahead)

this works only for 12 digits but I need for combination of words and digits

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to parse? That one example is not clearly showing your intent.

Answer (score 0):

`(r'^api/plus/([0-9a-zA-Z]{12})/$', hours_ahead)` should work.

Or, you can actually use `\w` instead of `[0-9a-zA-Z]`:

```
(r'^api/plus/(\w{12})/$', hours_ahead)
```

Note that `\w` matches letters, numbers (regardless of case), plus underscore (_).

Test:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "api/plus/12a23a11133ad"
>>> re.match(r"api/plus/([0-9a-zA-Z]{12})", s).group(1)
'12a23a11133ad'
>>> re.match(r"api/plus/(\w{12})", s).group(1)
'12a23a11133ad'
```

Comment: thanks but It is not helping me out. if u have other regex please post it

Comment: @ritu I've changed `+` to `{12}` - is it ok now? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: in url.py (r'^add/(?P<id>(\w{12})', 'api.plus.function') and url is api/plus/12a23a11133ad but 12a23a11133ad  can be change may be 34a23a11123ed

Comment: @ritu show the whole contents of your `urls.py` (include it into the question).